# What do I have to worry about when using a stainless steel pan as opposed to nonstick?

Tags: pan, stainless-steel

I've been using nonstick pans exclusively all my life. Most recently, after doing a lot of research, I decided to buy a stainless steel sauté pan (IKEA).

Do I need to handle it differently during cooking? Do I have to be careful when washing? What are some things I will have to watch out for since I'm used to nonstick pans?

**EDIT:** I decided to split this question about cast iron and stainless steel pans into two questions. The question about cast iron skillets can be found [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/69084/what-do-i-have-to-worry-about-when-using-a-cast-iron-skillet-as-opposed-to-nonst).

Answer (score 1):

Food will easily stick if you're not careful.

That seems a little obvious and facetious, but it is a separate concern than cast iron vs. nonstick. With cast iron, a good seasoning reduces sticking; you just have to be careful to maintain it. There's no comparable treatment for a stainless pan (the closest thing is, well, a non-stick coating) and so you are almost inevitably going to get some adhesion, especially when cooking proteins.

This is not always a bad thing. A pan sauce, for example, requires some degree of sticking so that you can deglaze the pan and utilize the good stuff in the *fond*. Many proteins will also "release" once the outer layer is well-seared, and be easier to remove without sticking, assuming you can let them go that long without overcooking as a whole. You must generally take care to use enough fat, and you'll likely have trouble no matter what with delicate fish, eggs, and thinner cuts of meat (keep your non-stick pan around for those). I also recommend finding a decently thick pan with good heft, as a very thin bottom layer won't diffuse the heat of the burner as well and produce hotter/colder spots on the cooking surface; this can cause problems with inconsistent sticking and release.

Stainless can also develop a sort of ["haze"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/52255/white-cloudy-areas-on-bottom-of-new-stainless-steel-skiillet?rq=1) on the bottom of the pan pretty quickly, which seems to be a mineral buildup of some kind. It doesn't really affect the performance of the pan, and it's easily cleaned off, but it can mar the shiny beauty of nice stainless.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You advise to use enough fat, which is the only thing related to "being careful". Are there other things I should pay attention to to avoid (unwanted) food sticking?

Comment: Make note of my comments related to delicate foods, too; some things just really aren't suited for cooking on stainless. Other than that, it's a quite durable cooking surface. You don't have to worry about scratching or  ruining the finish like you do with other materials, and it cleans up pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

**Cooking:**
Sticking will be the most noticeable issue. It takes some getting used to, here are some starter advice:

1. If you are frying, make sure your meat/fish/veg is properly dry. A wet food will only worsen the sticking.
2. Once you put the food in the pan, let it brown for at least 2 minutes before trying to move/shake it. This will allow to develop a brown coat and will help release the food relatively easily.

**Washing:**
Its more forgiving than a non-stick pan. A metal wool can take out most tough stains. Every once in a while, a cleaner like Barkeeper's Friend will help keep the shine.

If you haven't bought already, please take a look at try-ply clad or tri-ply base steel cookware, they are better at heat dissipation and usually of better quality.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I understood correctly, "try-ply" just means that there's a "sandwich" bottom consisting of an aluminum layer between the stainless steel, right? In that case, I believe [this one](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/10101169/) would be good enough (for a budget solution), correct?

Comment: Exactly. And yes, this one will be better to cook than a steel only or aluminum-only cookware.